# How to convert command parameter just before command is executed?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid in my view and DataGrid has cells with buttons, which have commands assigned. Now I wish to pass current row object (which sits in DataGrid.CurrentItem) to command execution logic.

My initial idea was to use CommandParameter with value converter, where converter would take DataGrid as parameter and extract required information from DataGrid into my own class - in such way I would avoid reference to DataGrid from my view model.

Problem is, that CommandParameter binding/value conversion is executed when grid is shown, meaning that there is no selected item yet.

Can I somehow avoid bringing DataGrid reference into my command execution logic, like deffer CommandParameter resolution until Command is performed or something like that?

Update: I need CurrentItem and CurrentColumn, I've realized, that CurrentItem might be accessible through binding of SelectedItem, so to avoid receiving answers with proposing use SelectedItem property.

Comment: Have you tried, I think the binding is executed when you trigger the command.

Comment: @Bolu - yes I've tried, bindings are executed when rendering data grid, not when clicking button.

Comment: what command parameter you want to send, I guess most of it can be  done with command binding of buttons

Comment: Wasn't aware it was WPF there is also a C# tag there to..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So my initial idea was close enough.

When I was binding CommandParameter to DataGrid, problem was, that when binding was resolving, DataGrid didn't knew yet what is CurrentColumn or CurrentCell or CurrentItem, so it was resolving to empty values.

So I changed binding to bind to DataGridCell instead - and problem was solved - Cell has ability to tell it's column and item it belongs to at the binding resolution time, so when command was fired, it had all the right data already.

Style was looking something like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},    
                          Path=DataContext[RowActionFeature].RowActionCommand}"                                                                                                      
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, 
                                   Converter={StaticResource DataGridCellToRowActionParametersConverter}}">
...
</Button>
```

And converter was something like this:

```
public class DataGridCellToRowActionParametersConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dataGridCell = value as DataGridCell;

        if (dataGridCell == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var dataRowView = dataGridCell.DataContext as DataRowView;
        var columnIndex = dataGridCell.Column.DisplayIndex;

        return new RowActionParameters
               {
                   Item = dataGridCell.DataContext,
                   ColumnPropertyName = dataGridCell.Column.SafeAccess(x => x.SortMemberPath),
                   DataRowView = dataRowView,                      
                   ColumnIndex = columnIndex
               };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Your command Parameter should be just `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`
  that way the parameter will be the  row `DataContext` where the button was clicked which is an instance your model.
- Cast your  parameter to your model inside your commadns `Execute`
  method.
- Say for example that you wanted to prevent the command from executing
  if the SelectedItem was null or if the Item has to be selected, then
  all you need is to return a bool from your `CanExecute` method based
  on whatever you want.

Comment: That solves the CurrentItem problem, but does not answer how to get CurrentColumn.

Comment: @Giedrius you have multiple buttons in the same row with the same  command?

Comment: yes, I use DataGridCell style, so in style is button and it's command described - so yes, I need somehow recognize what button that is.

Comment: @Giedrius sure you can pass multiple parameters to your command using an `IMultiValueConverter` for example you can pass the column index as an additional parameter, i am not sure what you are trying to do exactly without seeing your XAML so update the question with the relevant part of it, alsothe ViewModel has to know nothing about your view, everything is doable using XAML and converters

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I guess I haven't formulated my question well - main idea was if it is possible to defer CommandParameter resolution till moment command is about to be executed instead of having that at render time.